# Is it possible to use Python to change the privacy settings of multiple Facebook posts?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, facebook-graph-api

The new Facebook layout's search profile feature on top of each profile is terrifying me. I don't want people digging up stuff I said when I was young and stupid so easily with a click of a button on top of my profile. So I want to retroactively turn all my Facebook posts from before 2015 into having a privacy setting of "Only Me" (from "friends only"). What can I do and how can I do it?

I have a feeling that the word "API" will come up, but I've never really used APIs via Python. So assuming that I just know how to use Python, download and import modules and read the documentation of modules, what should my approach be?

Comment: The other option is to delete your Facebook account - I assume this destroys all your old posts too.

Comment: Maybe you can consider the approach proposed as in: https://github.com/pellaeon/fb-post-bulk-privacy-edit

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible via API.

Apps use to be able to modify user posts, only if those posts were made via the same app in the first place.
And even that possibility is gone now, because the publishing permission that was required for this, has been removed a while ago.

---

https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=privacy&section=masher offers the option
**Limit The Audience for Old Posts on Your Timeline**

More details can be found here, https://www.facebook.com/help/236898969688346

That only allows you to limit the visibility of public and friends-of-friends posts to only friends though. If you want them all to be “only me” … then you will have to go through them manually one by one now.

Comment: Just for the sake of discussion, how practical would it be to automate this task with Selenium?

Comment: @halfer I don’t know, not much experience with such tools. I guess it would depend on whether you can navigate through _all_ posts simply by triggering the infinite scroll mechanism again and again, and have Facebook not detect that or change the HTML structure at some point. Since there is no real pagination on the frontend side, otherwise I think you’d have trouble figuring out which posts you still need to modify, and which are already handled, resp. would go over the same posts again and again, if you have to re-start the process.